# How to detect if your ViewController was pushed from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

In my AppDelegate, I present a ViewController if the user types in my custom url scheme. It works as my ViewController is presented. However, I need to detect if my ViewController  was pushed from App delegate. What is the best method or course of action to do this? I only want to detect if it comes from AppDelegate and no where else.

```
           - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url

  ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

EDIT:To clarify what I am trying to do better, when appdelegate presents my viewcontroller I need to be able to detect inside my viewcontroller that it appeared because of the method inside app delegate. So kind of like this

ViewController

```
-(void) ViewDidLoad{
          if (this controller was presented from App delegate){
          do this
        }
         else{
          do nothing
          }
```

Comment: you should explain your primary issue more in details. What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you care about where it was pushed from? Is there any chance you push this controller from somewhere else?

Comment: App Delegate will never magically remove your controller, so if it gets pushed (I assume you mean 'dismissed' when you say 'pushed'), then your code did it, and you can see that. If you mean by 'pushed' that something was presented in front of it, then if that happens from your App Delegate, it is you doing it. If you mean by 'pushed' that some other bit of code presents another view controller in from of yours, you can always implement `viewWillDisappear`, but I don't know what you mean by 'only from AppDelegate' in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Do it simply like this :

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
       sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

     ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

// here you know that your controller is pushed from the AppDelegate, then you can do other things just after the push

    [controller callControllerPublicMethod];
    }
```

And when you push it in an other controller, simply do not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write your own custom initializer method in the `ViewController` and when called from the app delegate set a parameter to true, and everywhere else set it to false.